# MySQL - Find gaps in time series table

Tags: mysql, time-series, gaps-in-data

I have a time series table with values every 5 minute, with the following table structure:

```
DATETIME              VALUE
2000-01-01 00:00:00   4
2000-01-01 00:05:00   33
2000-01-01 00:10:00   8
2000-01-01 00:15:00   9
2000-01-01 00:25:00   13
2000-01-01 00:30:00   98
2000-01-01 00:35:00   23
2000-01-01 00:40:00   22
```

I want to identify all the places where there is a gap in the time series (i.e.: Line 5 in this example, there is no value for 2000-01-01 00:20:00).

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can use OUTER SELF JOIN.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How would that work exactly? I need to indentify where two records have more than 5 minutes difference between the two

Comment: You need to identify records that do not have "+5 minutes"  counterparts.

Comment: I understand that, but I cannot figure out what the syntax would be like. Can you please elaborate? Thank you.

Comment: Actually, I wrote a little c# console app that connects to the DB, fetch all the data and loops at the array to check. Takes a couple seconds to run and does the job. I know it's not answering my own question on how to do it in MySQL, but I feel like this is much more performant than anything I could have done in MySQL purely.

Comment: I doubt it's 'more' performant- but at 2 secs, who cares ;-)

Comment: For a table with 2.5 million records, I doubt it would have taken less than 2 seconds in MySQL